# Impacted wisdom tooth

Tags: dentistry, tooth-extraction, wisdom-teeth

I have a impacted wisdom tooth. I am thinking about having a dentist extract it.

What are the pros and cons when your molar is being extracted?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Only a dentist can say if you need to extract it we can't know for sure over the internet. We can however offer the pros and cons, so I rephrased your question slightly to make sure it stays on-topic (personal medical advice is strictly off-topic here). For more information on site policies please take our [tour] and visit the [help]. Thanks!